# What exactly was meant by ‘come not at your wives’?

Tags: exodus, moses

How was this commandment to be understood and why did Moses order it?

**Exodus 19:15 (KJV)**

> And he said unto the people, Be ready against the third day: come not at [your] wives.

**Exodus 19:15 (ESV)**

> And he said to the people, "Be ready for the third day; do not go near a woman."

Comment: See also 1 Samuel 21:4-6.

Comment: The Judaeo-Christian view of God is different from that of paganism, whose idols are the embodiment of human passions (Baal and Asherah, Zeus raping Europa, Mars laying with women whose men have gone to war, Eros, Cupid, Kama, etc).

Comment: Preemptively downvoted, since I strongly suspect an [ideological agenda behind the questions](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/38282?tab=questions); the user is probably trying to argue [Moses to have been a sexist as well](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/50352).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It meant that they should abstain from having sexual relations with their wives. This was because God was about to come down on Mount Sinai in the sight of all the people:

> **Exodus 19:11 (ESV)**
>   and be ready for the third day. For on the third day the LORD will come down on Mount Sinai in the sight of all the people.

Having sexual relations with their wives would have caused both them and their wives to become ceremonially unclean until evening:

> **Leviticus 15:18 (ESV)**
>   If a man lies with a woman and has an emission of semen, both of them shall bathe themselves in water and be unclean until the evening.

The people also were to wash their clothes:

> **Exodus 19:9-10 (ESV)**
>   And the LORD said to Moses, “Behold, I am coming to you in a thick cloud, that the people may hear when I speak with you, and may also believe you forever.” When Moses told the words of the people to the LORD, the LORD said to Moses, “Go to the people and consecrate them today and tomorrow, and let them wash their garments

Extra effort was to be made for the people to remain ceremonially clean for the appearance of God on the third day.

The word translated as "go near" in the ESV for Exodus 19:15 is **תִּגְּשׁוּ**, which is the second person masculine plural form of **נָגַשׁ**, which means to *approach* or *draw near* or *come near.*

[image: Nagash (draw near)]

As the [Brown-Driver-Briggs definition](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/620/mode/2up) above shows, in Exodus 19:15 it means to have sexual intercourse. Versions such as the New Living Translation (NLT) and the Christian Standard Bible (CSB) make this explicit:

> **Exodus 19:15 (NLT)**
>   He told them, “Get ready for the third day, and until then abstain from having sexual intercourse.”
>
> **Exodus 19:15 (CSB)**
>   He said to the people, “Be prepared by the third day. Do not have sexual relations with women.”

Comment: Good answer, only the text doesn’t say anything about sexual relations.

Comment: Hi @brewpixels, I added some extra information to my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: I love how you draw a red line box around the precise answer in BDB!  How do you do it?

Comment: Also, having sex dulls the mind, and God wanted everyone to be sharp as a tack.

Answer (score 1):

https://studyandobey.com/inductive-bible-study/exodus-studies/exodus-19/ has:

1 thing.

And here's another:
Why did God ask the Israelites to abstain from sexual relations in Exodus 19:15?

Then he said to the people, “Prepare yourselves for the third day. Abstain from sexual relations.”

Exodus 19:15

NIV - 15 Then he said to the people, "Prepare yourselves for the third day. Abstain from sexual relations.

Clarify • Share • Report • Asked February 16 2014 • Open uri20181019 20146 1h6c33q Pat Wood Supporter

```
Answers (1)
Discuss
```

Community answers are sorted based on votes. The higher the vote, the further up an answer is.
3
★
Mini Sung Park Father to 4 Boys & "Assiduous Contemplater" of the Word

This is the very first time where God Himself would appear before the nation of Israel. Until now, Moses had been like God to them but now in Chapter 19, God would descend on Mt. Sinai and speak directly to them.

In preparation for the personal meeting with God, He commanded several things (v. 10): consecrate them today and tomorrow (washing themselves) and wash their garments. In verse 15, Moses seems to add, "do not go near a woman" though it was not God's direct commandment. It seems to be a way to helping people to focus on meeting God as they prepare themselves for two days by washing themselves and their garments. Sexual acts, both leading up to and afterwards, can lead to distractions and defilement of their body (Lev 15:16).

Abstaining from sexual relation is equivalent to fasting as a way of giving up one of the basic human needs for a greater reason.

We can see Uriah the Hittite in 2 Samuel who refuses to share the bed with his wife during the time of war when his comrades are in battle. This was his way of showing solidarity and focus rather than indulging his needs.

From: https://ebible.com/questions/5966-why-did-god-ask-the-israelites-to-abstain-from-sexual-relations-in-exodus-19-15

Comment: Having sex dulls the mind, makes you temporarily stupid, and God wanted everyone's mind to be razor sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Ex 19:15 is well translated by the OP (unnamed, but probably ESV) version.  "Woman" here might also be rendered "wife" as well.

The allusion is obvious as rendered by many versions:

- NIV: Then he said to the people, "Prepare yourselves for the third day. Abstain from sexual relations."
- NLT: He told them, “Get ready for the third day, and until then abstain from having sexual intercourse.”
- CSB: He said to the people, "Be prepared by the third day. Do not have sexual relations with women."
- CEV: He told them to be ready in three days and not to have sex in the meantime.
- HCSB: He said to the people, "Be prepared by the third day. Do not have sexual relations with women."

That, is, God was preparing the people for the most sacred event in Israel's history, the giving of the Israelite covenant that would make of them a special people:

> Ex 19:5, 6 - Now if you will indeed obey My voice and keep My
> covenant, you will be My treasured possession out of all the
> nations—for the whole earth is Mine. And unto Me you shall be a
> kingdom of priests and a holy nation.’

In order to prepare the people, God asked them deny themselves for a few days in preparation so that they might have their minds concentrated on sacred matters.  The Pulpit commentary offers this background:

> Verse 15. - Come not at your wives. Compare 1 Samuel 21:4, 5; 1
> Corinthians 7:5. A similar obligation lay on the Egyptian priests
> (Porphyr. De Abstin. 4:7); and the idea which underlies it was
> widespread in the ancient world (See Herod. 1:198; Hesiod. Op. et Di.
> 733-4; Tibul. Carm. 2:1; 51:11, 12.)

What would happen if they did?  Probably not much (and that is the point) - they would not be prepared to fully appreciate what the LORD was about to share and it might make a lesser impact on their minds.